# Sorting of numeric values in python

Tags: python-2.7

Here i get the input from the user.
This is my code

```
num_array=list()
x=int(raw_input('Enter the numbers:'))
for i in range(int(x)):
n=raw_input("")
num_array.append(int(n))
print("\nThe numbers in ascending order are:%d" %(num_array.sort())
```

And when i want to print the numbers ,it is showing me an error.
I want output to look like this

```
 Enter the number:
 5
 4
 3
 2
 1
 The numbers in ascending order are 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Also, is your code really not indented under the `for`, or is this just a formatting error when you pasted it to [SO]?

Comment: I am not sure about the print statement.It shows as unindented block

Comment: I even tried that @hiroprotagonist still error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code

```
num_array=list()
x=int(raw_input('Enter the numbers:'))
for i in range(int(x)):
    n=raw_input("")
    num_array.append(int(n))
#print(sorted(num_array))
arr = sorted(num_array)
output = ""
for x in arr:
    output = output + str(x) + " "
print(output)
```

Comment: My output looks like [1,2,3,4,5] but i want it to be like dis 1 2 3 4 5 .What should i do to make it look like this @Syam Mohan

Comment: Yeah got the answer

Answer (score 1):

this may be what you want (replaced `%` print statement with `.format()` syntax).

`num_array.sort()` will sort your array but will return `None` (and that is what your print statement will try to print). `sorted` on the other hand returns a list.

```
num_array = []
x = int(raw_input('Enter length of the array: '))
for i in range(int(x)):
    n = raw_input("number '{}': ".format(i))
    num_array.append(int(n))
print("\nThe numbers in ascending order are: {}".format(sorted(num_array)))
```

if you do not want the output to look like a python list you could to this:

```
sorted_str = ' '.join(str(n) for n in sorted(num_array))
print("\nThe numbers in ascending order are: {}".format(sorted_str))
```

Comment: Say I know the length of the array i.e 5.How can we change the code without asking for the length of the array??

Comment: you replace the `x=...` line with `x=5`.

Comment: No. I am trying to get the list of numbers directly. My output should look like this:   Enter the numbers:
5
4
1
2
3

The numbers in ascending order are 1 2 3 4 5

Comment: This is my error File "Main.py", line 7
    print("\nThe numbers in ascending order are: {}".format(sorted_str)))
                                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: File "Main.py", line 6, in 
    sorted_str = ' '.join(sorted(num_array))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: Look at my output above carefully in the edit . Its exactly the same which i want :(